# 3rd party webserver authentication

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, authorization, one-time-password

I'm developing a web application which includes two separate servers:

- A trusted server for private key operations
- A webserver providing the frontend

Some operations on the webserver require private key operations. The webserver then asks the trusted server to perform the operation. In order to prevent misuse, the client needs to authorize each such request by providing a one-time password based on a pre-shared secret. The request should be authenticated by the webserver.

I was thinking about using a Popup in which the OTP should be entered. However, I'm not sure how to add authentication by the webserver in this scenario. Can you provide me with an idea how to achieve that?